# Instagram graph API rate limiting

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We have a live App that uses the Instagram platform API to get basic data of users. This app requires to update its user's data on a daily basis.
Endpoints that we use in our app:
1. /users/self/
2. /users/self/media/recent/

Now we want to migrate our app to use the new Instagram Graph API (v3.3). We have some queries :
   1. Which rate limiting will be applied to our app?
     a.  Application-level rate limiting, or
     b. Instagram rate limiting (business use case rate limiting)

2. If Instagram rate limiting is imposed on our app, then how do we get data of new users that don't have any posts or those users that didn't post any content in the last 24 hours? What will be the rate limit in these cases?
3. When will the Instagram platform API deprecate completely?